# WPF ListBoxItem Events

Tags: wpf, mvvm, listboxitem

One of those 'Why is this so hard?" questions.

I have a `ListBox` (containing details of share portfolios). The listbox item uses a grid to display attributes of the portfolio. Source is a list of portfolios in the View Model.

`ListBox` is multiselect - when selection changes, a list of the constituents of the selected portfolios is re-populated.

What I want to do is put a button (or menu or whatever) on the listboxitem to display a list of possible actions (Trade, Unitise, Delete etc).

When an action is selected I need to execute the action against the appropriate portfolio. Ideally I want the actions to be available for both selected and unselected items.

I can handle the event, but how do I detect which item (portfolio) the user selected? I've looked at GotFocus() but it doesn't seem to fire.

In other words if a control in a Listboxitem, fires an event, how does the event 'know' which `ListBoxItem` raised it?

Answer (score 1):

For me, the solution here, seen as you mentioned MVVM, would be to have the `ListBox` populated by a collection of ViewModels, e.g., something like `ObservableCollection<PortfolioViewModel>`.

It would then just be a case of binding the `Command` property of the `Button` to an `ICommand` on the ViewModel that executes whatever work you need doing.

Comment: I think I see where you're coming from.

Currently the listbox is bound to a collection of the Portfolio class, which just contains properties (Id, Name, Value ....), but there's no reason the class couldn't also contain methods, or commands.

I'll spin that up, see if it flies.

Thanks, Chris.

Answer (score 0):

> I can handle the event, but how do I detect which item (portfolio) the user selected? I've looked at `GotFocus()` but it doesn't seem to fire.

You could cast the `DataContext` of the clicked `Button` to the corresponding object in te `ListBox`, e.g.:

```
private void DeleteButton_Clicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Button deleteButton = sender as Button;
    var portfolio = deleteButton.DataContext as Portfolio; //or whatever your type is called

    //access any members of the portfolio...
}
```